# Why is a resolution missing from Xorg session, but not in Wayland?

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, xrandr, wayland, resolution

I run Ubuntu 22.10 on Dell XPS 13 2-in-1 2020. Its graphic card is Mesa Intel® Xe (TGL GT2). I noticed the following:

- When I log in to the Ubuntu desktop environment (which is default), I can choose the 1440x900 resolution (16x10 aspect ratio).
- When I log in to Ubuntu on Xorg desktop environment, the 1440x900 resolution is not offered as an option.
  I see the same behaviour through both the GUI (Settings > Display), and command line (xrandr). Also, the above resolution was available on Xorg in Ubuntu 22.04.

Why is this happenning? How can I re-enable 1440x900 resolution for the Xorg environment again?